# How to use __get__ and __set__ (python descriptors)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, descriptor

I'm new to using descriptors and I think I have a good understanding on how they work but I have come across a problem and i'm not sure how to fix it.

## Code

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        def __get__(self,instance, owner):
            return 10
        def __set__(self,instance,value):
            raise Exception
    bar=Bar()

print(Foo.bar)
Foo.bar=5
print(Foo.bar)
```

## Output

```
>>> 10
>>> 5
```

Im trying to make `bar` a constant for testing purposes, I know about the `property` decorator but I prefer using descriptors.

First I print out the value of `bar` to see if `__get__` works - and it does, the output is `10`.

But then when I assign `5` to `bar` the expected result would be an exception but instead what happens is `5` gets assigned to `bar` despite specifying `__set__` so when I print again the second output is `5`.

#### Can someone tell me why the error isn't being raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__):

> `object.__set__(self, instance, value)`
>
> Called to set the attribute on an instance `instance` of the owner class to a new value, `value`.

In your code, `Foo.bar = 5` is setting the class attribute, not an instance attribute. If you do use an instance (without first setting `Foo.bar = 5`, which overrides your descriptor), then you get an exception as expected:

```py
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
10
>>> f.bar = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __set__
Exception
```

If you want the `__set__` behaviour to apply when the class attribute is set, then the class itself needs to be an instance of a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) which uses the descriptor:

```py
class FooMeta(type):
    class Bar:
        def __get__(self,instance, owner):
            return 10
        def __set__(self,instance,value):
            raise Exception
    bar = Bar()

class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    pass
```

Testing:

```py
>>> Foo.bar
10
>>> Foo.bar = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __set__
Exception
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, but is there a way to use just one class? So the combination of `FooMeta` and `Foo`?